# How can I delay a Stripe transaction until a certain event?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I need to find a way to essentially have two parties (buyer and seller) agree to the terms of a deal, and then delay the execution of the transaction until they have met in real life and each agree to finish the deal (perhaps via a button on their phone).

Is this kind of transaction structure possible with Stripe? Or is there another payments API I should take a look at?

Actually, what I'd truly like to be able to do is this: once the buyer and seller agree to the terms of the deal (price, etc), the buyer's money actually leaves his account and goes somewhere else, where it's "held" until the deal either succeeds (both parties agree and then the buyer's money goes into the seller's account) or the deal fails, in which case the buyer's money returns to his/her account.

Hopefully that didn't sound too convoluted, but is something like this possible with Stripe/any other payments API? Would greatly appreciate any guidance here!

Comment: I suggest you research about 'pre-authorization' and 'capture' of funds.

Comment: Thanks Alex! This is exactly what I was looking to start reading up on.